# Постоянная ошибка с tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlet

Когда форма обрабатывается сервлетом `Login`, в первой же строчке появляется ошибка:

> cannot be cast to org.apache.catalina.connector.requestfacade

`Login` servlet:

```
package servlet;

import temp.getSession;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import static temp.getSession.status;

@WebServlet("/login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        String log = request.getParameter("log");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        new getSession(log,pass);
        if(status){
            response.getWriter().print("Hi " + log);
            response.sendRedirect("localhost:3030/main.jsp");
        }else{
            response.getWriter().println("incorrect!");
        }
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
package servlet;

import temp.getSession;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


import static temp.getSession.status;


@WebServlet(
        name = "login",
        description = "login",
        urlPatterns = "/login"
)

public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        String log = request.getParameter("log");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        new getSession(log,pass);
        if(status){
            response.getWriter().print("Hi " + log);
            response.sendRedirect("localhost:3030/main.jsp");
        }else{
            response.getWriter().println("incorrect!");
        }
    }

}
```